# Using Jest with Puppeteer : EReferenceError : xxx is not defined

Tags: puppeteer, jest-puppeteer

when learn puppeteer/jest, many tutorial articles example are the same,like:

```
const timeout = 10000;

beforeAll(async () => {
    await page.goto(URL, { waitUntil: "domcontentloaded" });
});

describe("Test title and header of the homepage", () => {
    test("Title of the page", async () => {
        const title = await page.title();

        expect(title).toBe("Learn Web Development with free Classes and Tutorials - Sabe.io");
    }, timeout);

    test("Header of the page", async () => {
        const h1Handle = await page.$("h1");
        const html = await page.evaluate(h1Handle => h1Handle.innerHTML, h1Handle);

        expect(html).toBe("Become a better developer");
    }, timeout);
});
```

and the jest.config.js like:

```
module.exports = {
    preset: "jest-puppeteer",
    globals: {
        URL: "https://sabe.io"
    },
    testMatch: [
        "**/test/**/*.test.js"
    ],
    verbose: true
}
```

and they all success in article, but when i run that code on local, get an error :

```
ProtocolError: Protocol error (Page.navigate): Invalid parameters Failed to deserialize params.url - BINDINGS: mandatory field missing at position 49
```

or

```
ReferenceError: URL is not defined
```

does anybody get the same error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it success when jest.config.js chenge like this:

```
module.exports = {
//    preset: "jest-puppeteer", // remove that
    globals: {
        URL: "https://sabe.io"
    },
    testMatch: [
        "**/test/**/*.test.js"
    ],
    verbose: true
}
```